# Setting up exception for error in nagios

Tags: nagios

I am not sure if this is possible but I would like to set up exception where Nagios does not report on a few checks.

e.g. On one of our server, one of the ram component is broken and its been broken for a while. We are not going to fix as it does not really impact any of the workings of server. However, that Notification sits on nagios's "unhandled" services page.

Is there a way to create "exception" so that we do not see this error or it sits under different location?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lUMv.png)

Comment: How do you get this alarm, what probe do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer,

Way to do it is to "acknowledge" error.

If we "acknowledge" error then that error will be removed from "unhandled" to acknowledge.

how to do it

Click on error notification > when it takes you to details page on the right-hand side you should have "service commands" in here you should see, "Acknowledge this error"

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to be able to see the check, you can use the "Acknowledge this service problem" option on the service information page - this will remove it from showing on the Problems > Services (Unhandled) page but will still show on the Problems > Services page. If/when the service returns to an OK state, it will disappear from Problems > Services, the acknowledgement and comment will be removed (unless you set the comment as persistent, of course) and the next time it changes to a state WARNING, CRITICAL or UNKNOWN, it will appear on the Problems > Services (Unhandled) page.

Personally, I would recommend using acknowledgements only for things that are temporary problems; if it is for something that you will never fix, it would be better to exclude this host from the service check definition by using an exclamation mark before its name in the `host_name` directive (or you could set up a hostgroup and put an exclamation mark before it in the `hostgroup_name` directive if you want to exclude a lot of servers).

In this example, the service check would apply to the hostgroup `dell-servers` but not those servers which are also in the hostgroup `non-esxi-servers` (and it would also exclude hosts `server01` and `server02` which we'll assume are also in the `dell-servers` hostgroup).

```
define service{
    use                    generic-service
    service_description    ESXI Service
    host_name              !server01,!server02
    hostgroup_name         dell-servers,!non-esxi-servers
    }
```

Comment: Hi Roddie, Thanks for the feedback. Will this even work for a single machine? e.g. i have 10 machines running XYZ service and I only want to ignore a notice from few of it? Can i comment like "!server01,!server02,server03"" ?

Comment: That's right - I've updated my answer to include that. In your comment you've written `!server01,!server02,server03`, not sure if that's a typo but just to clarify that would mean it applies to server03 and excludes server01 and server02